# Multi-tenant CMS with API endpoint

Tags: content-management-system, multi-tenant

We are looking for a CMS that built to expose content over API like contentful, or prismic. However our requirement is that needs to be multi-tenant. So one set of fields but many clients and languages per client in a structure like this.

```
fields/pages/container -> Client 1 -> English
                                   -> Greek
                          Client 2 -> Japanese
                                   -> Mandarin
```

Happy do do workarounds and hacks. Also cloud-based service would work nicely.

Suggestions?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Prismic.io seemed to be a good candiate for this anyway!